# Magento 2.3.4 update: All Rest API are getting 500 error

Tags: shipping-methods, rest-api, magento2.3.4

I've recently updated my Magento 2.3.4. Now getting 500 error for all the Magento REST API being used on checkout, cart, or any other pages.

I've checked for System log but not getting anything related to error except 500error on browser network.
Please suggest the solutions If someone has encountered the same issue.

Below is the error screenshot

[image]

Comment: you need to show us the error you have: you can find this error in your webserver error log

Comment: It is Authorization Circular dependency issue on executing the rest API

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks but I found the answer it, was Mirasvit extension di.xml file, which was causing the issue.
```

Below is the code which was causing the issue so, I've commented it for now and my website is working fine.

```
<type name="Magento\Authorization\Model\CompositeUserContext">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="userContexts" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="giftRegistrantUserContext" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="object">Mirasvit\Giftr\Model\Authorization\GiftRegistrantSessionUserContext</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```